# Android / iOS - BLE - wake up a terminated application when a BLE device connects

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, background-process

Iam creating an iOS and an Android application that read some data from a bluetooth sensor and saves them in a db.

I want to give the ability to save the sensor's data even when the application is terminated.

fyi. I have already managed to read the sensor in both iOS and Android while the app is the background.

But my concern is on how to make the following scenario work:

-Sensor is disconnected from the phone
-User terminates the application from the task manager
-User connects (and pairs) the BLE sensor to the device
-The application wakes-up in the background and reads the sensor's output and then goes back to sleep.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ? I'm having similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813624/re-connect-bluetooth-device-when-app-is-terminated

Answer (score 1):

For iOS this is possible as described in Apple doc [Core Bluetooth Background Processing for iOS Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html).

For Android you could start a [Service](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html) (by your app and also on device boot) and (re)connect to the device.

Also you could post a local notification in iOS/Android background Service - and when the user touches it, start the BLE app.