# iOS app wake up with BLE not working as before on iOS9.3?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios9.3

There are previous topics about waking up an application from the background with BLE advertisement (e.g. [How to wake up iOS app with bluetooth signal (BLE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19932090/how-to-wake-up-ios-app-with-bluetooth-signal-ble), [Android / iOS - BLE - wake up a terminated application when a BLE device connects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397980/android-ios-ble-wake-up-a-terminated-application-when-a-ble-device-connect)).

However my question is not about that since we had this feature working fine up to **iOS 9.2** included.

Coming **iOS 9.3** the feature doesn't work as it used to work before, it seems that the terminated by user swiping off the application is not woken up. Nothing changed on the **BLE** advertisement originator.
After a recheck of various parameters and reading of Apple documentation, nothing springs to our minds. Neither Apple documentation mention any change, unless we missed something.

Have other people notice this issue? Are you aware of a solution?

We wrote to Apple and we are pending on an answer but maybe somebody here has the correct tip.

Many thanks in advance for the attention.

**UPDATE**: After more testing, it seems that only when the user swipes the application out the wake up doesn't work like it used to in **iOS 9.2**
Initial testing were more manual and gave us the impression that there was an underlying issue. However not sure why this change took place without any notification from Apple. - Above text was amended based on the update -

**UPDATE 2**: This issue is not present anymore in **iOS 10**.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out after a reply from Apple that this is a (new) intended behaviour.

Comment: However it had been reverted in **iOS 10.0** so the **iOS 9.2** behaviour looks to be back.

Answer (score 0):

didEnterRegion/didExitRegion events stopped working from the background after update to 9.3

I have an app that has been working almost perfectly for the last 6 months, and after the update these events are no longer getting called. I started this app over last year when I heard about iOS9 coming out, and when I couldn't get the old one working, I started a new one using Swift instead.

After some time and a LOT of driving in and out of my Region, I got the app to work more reliably than it ever had before. I have several devices using the app, and when all of them updated to iOS9.3/9.3.1, the app stopped calling didEnterRegion/didExitRegion events completely.

I have a ticket open with Apple, but I am getting a lot of push back about the service, and that 9.3 didn't change background location at all.

My devices use AT&T of Verizon, we have tried wi-fi assist on and off, I even wiped a system, formatted the HD, installed El Capitan, and XCode 7.3, and it's hasn't helped.

I also found an issue with the Devices Tool, and when you download the Container, and open package, the Documents folder is empty. I'm not getting a warm fuzzy feeling for Apple right now, and I am sure someone is feeling my MEGA MIND WEDGIE at this moment.

Help....

Comment: Thanks for the posting but I'm afraid it sounds a bit of topic to me since your issue is not related to BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy). What do you think?