# Re-Connect Bluetooth Low Energy iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm working on CoreBluetooth for 5 months. There is a topic which still I don't understand. I'm successfully connected and paired ble device with ios device in background and foreground. But when app is terminated by user, ble device disconnected. Some people say : application doesn't wake up when terminated by user via ble device. But I don't agree with them. Because 
 Tile App https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tile-find-lost-keys-phone/id664939913?mt=8 doing this. I connect Tile device from Tile app then I swipe-kill app from the application list. Then I click tile button and Tile re-connect ble device. How can I do same thing with using CoreBluetooth ? I asked similar question on stackoverflow:
 [Re-connect bluetooth device when app is terminated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813624/re-connect-bluetooth-device-when-app-is-terminated)

Comment: Did you get any solution to this?